# English to PigLatin Conversion of a Sentence

Tags: c#, string, foreach, indexof

I am making a program to convert English to PigLatin. However, my solution only seems to work with one word. If I enter in more than ond word, only the last is translated.

> testing one translation

Would simply output:

> translationway

I've looked at some solutions, but most are in the same fashion as mine, or use "simplified" solutions beyond the scope of my knowledge.

Code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence to convert to PigLatin:");
        string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
        string pigLatin = ToPigLatin(sentence);
        Console.WriteLine(pigLatin);
    }

    static string ToPigLatin (string sentence)
    {            
        string firstLetter,
               restOfWord,
               vowels = "AEIOUaeio";
        int currentLetter;

        foreach (string word in sentence.Split())
        {
            firstLetter = sentence.Substring(0, 1);
            restOfWord = sentence.Substring(1, sentence.Length - 1);
            currentLetter = vowels.IndexOf(firstLetter);

            if (currentLetter == -1)
            {
                sentence = restOfWord + firstLetter + "ay";
            }
            else
            {
                sentence = word + "way";
            }
        }
        return sentence;
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

---

### Edit

Thanks to great feedback, I've updated my code:

```
    static string ToPigLatin (string sentence)
    {
        
        const string vowels = "AEIOUaeio";
        List<string> pigWords = new List<string>();

        foreach (string word in sentence.Split(' '))
        {
            string firstLetter = word.Substring(0, 1);
            string restOfWord = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
            int currentLetter = vowels.IndexOf(firstLetter);

            if (currentLetter == -1)
            {
                pigWords.Add(restOfWord + firstLetter + "ay");
            }
            else
            {
                pigWords.Add(word + "way");
            }
        }
        return string.Join(" ", pigWords);
    }
```

Would it be very complex to adapt this code to work with consonant clusters?

For example, right now *testing one translation* prints as:

> estingtay oneway ranslationtay

While, as I understand PigLatin rules, it should read:

> estingtay oneway anslationtray

Comment: Among other things, you'll want to call `SubString` on `word` instead of `sentence` inside your loop. That, and you're overwriting `sentence` each time so after the first cycle it always contains the previous piggified word (which, combined, can result in incorrect piggification).

Comment: For consonant clusters, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place `+=` instead of `=` here:

```
if (currentLetter == -1)
{
    sentence += restOfWord + firstLetter + "ay";
}
else
{
    sentence += word + "way";
}
```

On your version, you were overriding the sentence in each iteration of your loop

---

### Edit

I've made a *lot* of changes to the code:

```
public static string ToPigLatin(string sentence)
{
    const string vowels = "AEIOUaeio";
    List<string> newWords = new List<string>();

    foreach (string word in sentence.Split(' '))
    {
        string firstLetter = word.Substring(0, 1);
        string restOfWord = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
        int currentLetter = vowels.IndexOf(firstLetter);

        if (currentLetter == -1)
        {
            newWords.Add(restOfWord + firstLetter + "ay");
        }
        else
        {
            newWords.Add(word + "way");
        }
    }
    return string.Join(" ", newWords);
}
```

As [Panagiotis-Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) said, and he's damn right, don't build your output *on* your input but *with* your input. Thus, I added the `newWords` list (some might prefer a StringBuilder, I don't).

You were misusing your variable in your loop, especially with the `Substrings` calls, it's now fixed.

If you have any question on this, don't hesitate.

Comment: Far better: *don't* use the input parameter to construct the output. Use a StringBuilder and StringBuilder.Append to build the response and return it as a single string.

Comment: It would be better to fix this answer. Using an input parameter as a temporary variable is a very bad idea

Comment: And while you are at it, add a space between the words.

Comment: @Thomas 
 
Oh jeez, how silly of me. What does putting ' ' in the sentence.Split do?

Comment: @ryderd it split sentence on every space char

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence to convert to PigLatin:");
            string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
            var pigLatin = GetSentenceInPigLatin(sentence);
            Console.WriteLine(pigLatin);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string GetSentenceInPigLatin(string sentence)
        {
            const string vowels = "AEIOUaeio";
            var returnSentence = "";
            foreach (var word in sentence.Split())
            {
                var firstLetter = word.Substring(0, 1);
                var restOfWord = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
                var currentLetter = vowels.IndexOf(firstLetter, StringComparison.Ordinal);

                if (currentLetter == -1)
                {
                    returnSentence += restOfWord + firstLetter + "ay ";
                }
                else
                {
                    returnSentence += word + "way ";
                }
            }
            return returnSentence;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a short LINQ implementation for this:

```
string.Join(" ", "testing one translation".Split(' ')
    .Select(word => "aeiouy".Contains(word[0])
            ? word.Skip(1).Concat(word.Take(1))
            : word.ToCharArray())
    .Select(word => word.Concat("way".ToCharArray()))
    .Select(word => string.Concat(word)));
```

Output: "testingway neoway translationway"

Of course, I'd probably refactor it to something like this:

```
"testing one translation"
    .Split(' ')
    .Select(word => word.ToCharsWithStartingVowelLast())
    .Select(word => word.WithEnding("way"))
    .Select(word => string.Concat(word))
    .Join(' ');

static class Extensions {
    public static IEnumerable<char> ToCharsWithStartingVowelLast(this string word)
    {
        return "aeiouy".Contains(word[0])
            ? word.Skip(1).Concat(word.Take(1))
            : word.ToCharArray();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<char> WithEnding(this IEnumerable<char> word, string ending)
    {
        return word.Concat(ending.ToCharArray())
    }
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>> words, char separator)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, words.Select(word => string.Concat(word)));
    }
}
```

**Update:**

With your edit, you asked about consonant clusters. One of the things I like about doing this with LINQ is that it's pretty simple to just update that part of the pipeline, and make it all work:

```
 public static IEnumerable<char> ToCharsWithStartingConsonantsLast(this string word)
{
    return word.SkipWhile(c => c.IsConsonant()).Concat(word.TakeWhile(c => c.IsConsonant()));
}

public static bool IsConsonant(this char c)
{
    return !"aeiouy".Contains(c);
}
```

The entire pipeline, without refactoring to extension methods, now looks like this:

```
string.Join(" ", "testing one translation".Split(' ')
    .Select(word => word.SkipWhile(c => !"aeiouy".Contains(c)).Concat(word.TakeWhile(c => !"aeiou".Contains(c))))
    .Select(word => word.Concat("way".ToCharArray()))
    .Select(word => string.Concat(word)))
```

and outputs `"estingtway oneway anslationtrway"`.

**Update 2:**

I noticed I wasn't handling word endings correctly. Here's an update that takes care of only adding `w` to the ending when the word (without the ending) ends with a vowel:

```
string.Join(" ", "testing one translation".Split(' ')
    .Select(word => word.SkipWhile(c => !"aeiouy".Contains(c)).Concat(word.TakeWhile(c => !"aeiou".Contains(c))))
    .Select(word =>
    {
        var ending = "aeiouy".Contains(word.Last()) ? "way" : "ay";
        return word.Concat(ending.ToCharArray());
    })
    .Select(word => string.Concat(word)))
```

Output: `"estingtay oneway anslationtray"`. Note how it's *only* the step that handles adding the ending that changed - all other parts of the algorithm were unchanged.

Given how simple this now is, I'd probably only use two extension methods: `Join(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>> words, char separator)` and `IsConsonant(this char c)` (the implementation of the latter should be easy given the code samples above). This yields the following final implementation:

```
"testing one translation"
        .Split(' ')
        .Select(word => word.SkipWhile(c => !c.IsVowel()).Concat(word.TakeWhile(c => c.IsVowel())))
        .Select(word => word.Concat((word.Last().IsVowel() ? "way" : "ay").ToCharArray()))
        .Select(word => string.Concat(word))
        .Join(" ")
```

It's also really easy to see here what we do to translate:

1. Split the sentence into words
2. Shuffle any consonants to the end of the word (it's admittedly not apparent at first sight that this is what happens, but I can't find a simpler way to express it except by wrapping it in an extension method)
3. Add the ending
4. Convert `IEnumerable<char>`s to `string`s
5. Re-join the words into a sentence

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind. However, I am not to the point of using LINQ as of yet.

Comment: Although LINQ might seem overwhelming at first, it quickly becomes a very nice way to think only about a small part of the problem at hand at a time, allowing surprisingly elegant solutions to comparably complicated problems. Martin Fowler wrote (in a language-agnostic way) about the topic of Collection Pipelines a while ago - I really recommend giving it a read: http://martinfowler.com/articles/collection-pipeline/